# How to restart activity with singleInstance activity from other activity

Tags: android

How to replace or restart activity with singleinstance from another activity.

i have two activity, ActivityA and ActivityB.

in manifest:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:label="@string/activityA"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityB"
    android:label="@string/activityB" />
```

My question, how to restart ActivityA from method in ActivityB.
Mycode no in ActivityB is:

```
class ActivityB extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button rButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);
        rButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 restartActivityA();
            }
        });
    }

    public void restartActivityA() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(intent);
       this.finish();
    }
}
```

If i click the button, so not restart.

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error when running this code by start first activity as `startActivity(intent);` ?

Comment: yes, it there are, i have edit my post.

Comment: not yet, what addflags use to this problem. thanks.

Comment: @HaicalRams how do you calling `ActivityB` from `ActivityA`?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your `ActivityA` :

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);           
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Call ActivityB like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Thanks.

Comment: i have solved, i get solved via send broadcaster. but i forget the link, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it will help.

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();//it will return the intent for current activity
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I have Log.d("MyLog","Activitystart"); in onCreate ActivityA to see what ActivityA start or not.