# recreate /restart activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, recreate

I have seen this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293467/how-to-restart-activity-with-singleinstance-activity-from-other-activity) but didn't get good answers and my situation is a little bit different. I have 2 activities A and B. From Activity A I launch Activity B but activity A must stay opened, now after I login in Activity B I save some data in Shared Preferences and I need the layout in Activity A to change according to the shared preferences values, so after login Activity A must recreate to apply changes but still should be behind Activity B.

So my question is it possible to recreate Activity A from Activity B??

Comment: Why do you need activity A to be recreated? Why don't you just send a message from activity B to activity A after logging in to tell activity A to update itself. There are a few ways to do so, but IMO most natural way in this case is use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int) to start activity B from activity A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean with "activity A must stay opened" though so you'll have to figure out that part or give a more detailed explanation. Do you mean Activity B overlays Activity A? I'll assume that.

I suggest you to use 3 fragments in Activity A.
One fragment for the initial layout and another one for the new layout.
Then another fragment instead of Activity B, I'll call it FragmentB.

In `FragmentB` create a Callback inner interface.

```
public interface Callbacks {
    void onLoggedIn();
}
```

Then make Activity A implement this callback

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements FragmentB.Callbacks {

//rest of the activity...

 @Override
    public void onLoggedIn() {

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment())
                            .commit();
}
}
```

Obviously you can choose any name you like for `ActivityA`, `FragmentB`, `Callbacks`, `onLOggedIn` and `SecondFragment`.
Where `SecondFragment` is the name of the fragment that contains the layout after being logged in in `FragmentB`.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Instead of **recreate* your activity, you should use `startActivityForResult` and update your activity on `onActivityResult`

e.g.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     ...

     static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
             // When the user center presses, let them pick a contact.
             startActivityForResult(
                 new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                 new Uri("content://contacts")),
                 PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
            return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
                 // to the user.
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data));
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to fetch the value from shared preferences and update to layout in OnResume() method of activity where like oncreate() etc.:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here... to get sharedpreferences

}
```